# switching layouts in Qt

Tags: qt, layout, qt4

I have 2 layouts - `layout1` and `layout2`. Let's say both are entirely different in terms of number of types of widget in them. Now I have 2 buttons `but1` and `but2`. When `but1` is cliked `layout1` is activated and when `but2` is clicked `layout2` is activated. 
How can I achieve this in Qt?

**Note:**
I don't want to delete my widgets( or layouts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
QStackedWidget* stackedWidget = new QStackedWidget;
QWidget* parentLayout1 = new QWidget;
QWidget* parentLayout2 = new QWidget;
QGridLayout* layout1 = new QGridLayout(parentLayout1);
QGridLayout* layout2 = new QGridLayout(parentLayout2);
stackedWidget->addWidget(parentLayout1);
stackedWidget->addWidget(parentLayout2);
stackedWidget->widget(1)->show();
```

Then hide and show them as you need, I tried QStackedLayout myself for the problem but I had trouble getting it working but the above solution should work fine. I used it on a project that I'm working on at the moment and the performance for switching widgets is probably the same as the QStackedLayout. Obviously what I gave you there is the bare bones of the code, but that should help you on your way. Any subsequent questions let me know. Also you can use whatever type of layout you want, doesn't have to be QGridLayout, thats just what I used.

Comment: Actually I was expecting something like stackedWidget->addLayout(layout1);    wherein my layout contains whole lot of different widgets and layouts. For example let's say: in layout1 I have button1 and label1. similarly for layout2. How do I use QStackedWidget to switch between the 2 layouts?

Comment: Because the layouts are children of the two widgets, so the QWidgets parentLayout1 and parentLayout2 when you show them it will show the layouts. I should add that whatever you populate the two layouts with when they have a QWidget as the parent then all the stuff in the layout will be shown when the parent widget is shown. So when I say `stackedWidget->widget(1)->show();` what I'm doing is showing the first widget which has the child layout and this will show the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You should use QStackedLayout or QStackedWidget for this.